# Running script with ssh

Tags: shell, ssh, ksh

I work with machine A and I want to run a script that exists in machine B.

I did the ordinary command:

```
ssh user@machine_B_adress '. script.sh'
```

the problem is that I used in the script some commands that cannot be interpret with machine A. So I get command not found: (for example)

```
ksh: sqlplus:  not found
```

---

I tried to open a shh by:
ssh user@machine_B_adress

and then run the script, it works!!!

Comment: Have you tried ssh user@machine_B_address '/bin/bash -l .script.sh'?

Comment: bash is not installed in the remote machine and I can't install it; Simply, coz I m not allowed to do it

Comment: I get:
ksh: /bin/bash:  not found

Comment: could you run the following commands and paste the output: when logged in: `which sqlplus` `ps  -ef | grep $$ | grep -v grep` and `echo "$PATH"` and also all 3 as `ssh user@machine_B_adress 'which sqlplus'` ?

Comment: I get:
no sqlplus in /usr/bin /etc ... after executing ssh user@machine_B_adress 'which sqlplus'

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the shell for user@machine_B is bash, the first example `'ssh user@machine_B_adress '. script.sh'`, bash sets up the shell env differently for interactive/non-interactive sessions.

See `man bash` about interactive shells

Looks like you can emulate the interactive environment by adding a `bash -l -c`

```
$ ssh user@machine_B_address "bash -l -c '. script.sh'
```

My quick test, I added debug echo to **.bash_profile** of the remote user

```
$ ssh foouser@jdsrpi1 "bash --login -c '. foo.sh'"
```

This is file **.bash_profile**

```
foouser 

SHELL = /bin/bash

PATH = /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

Similar scenario for `ksh`

```
$ ssh kshuser@jdsdrop1.jimsander.io "date"
Tue Apr 18 11:52:43 EDT 2017

$ ssh kshuser@jdsdrop1 "ksh -l -c date"
```

This is SHELL(/usr/bin/ksh) file **.profile**

```
Tue Apr 18 11:53:24 EDT 2017
```

Comment: Thanks for responding; But if it's ksh?